What is the object of the verb 探る
I'm a little confused about the use of 探る (this link is related but I don't think it really answers my question). I can't work out if the grammatical object is the thing I'm seeking or the place I'm seeking it. Consider:

財布を探った。

I've seen this translated with two quite different meanings:

I felt around in my wallet (i.e. I have a credit card in my wallet but I can't find the card)
I felt around for my wallet (i.e. I have my wallet in my bag but I can't find the wallet)

Which of these two is correct, or can it be either depending on the context?
How would I combine both ideas i.e. "I felt around for my wallet in my bag"?

The basic meaning of ～を探る is to use your sense of touch only on some object to get an idea of its size or shape, or to find something inside of that object.
I don't think your translations for 財布を探った are correct.
In 1, the first part "I felt around in my wallet" sounds alright to me but it does not necessarily imply that you cannot find something in your wallet. 探る simply refers to the action of feeling your wallet. More context is needed to determine what you are trying to do with this action.
Your second translation is also wrong. It sounds like you are looking for a wallet, so it is understood as 財布を捜した.
To say "feel in X for Y," you can use Yを捜してXを探る. Your second translation can be understood as 財布を捜してカバンを探った.
